# removing certain objects from list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a list of objects

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string device_code { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }
    public string authentication_token { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
```

while returning the list i want to remove "device_code" and "device_type" from the list and return the list only with "id","authentication_token" and "status".
How can I delete certain objects?

Comment: What means you want to remove those properties? The object itself has several properties, you want to make them `null`(in case of reference types)  or you want to remove these objects from the list? But then i don't understand how "device_code" and "device_type" are related.

Comment: "I have a list" no you don't. Your code example does not contain a list; it contains a data structure. If a value in a data structure is missing, it is conventional to set it to `null`. It is only in special cases that you would literally remove a property (which would require you to define another class).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, create another class containing properties that are required and then return its object using the list you have created.

> Original Class

```
public class Data {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string device_code { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }
    public string authentication_token { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

> Class That will be returned

```
public class DataTobeReturned {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string authentication_token { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose you have list like

```
List<Data> list = // some data;
```

You can do

```
List<DataTobeReturned> list2 = list.Select(x => new DataTobeReturned { x.id, x.Status, x.authentication_token}).ToList();
```

Simply return the `list2` object.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your object to another type that will contain only needed properties. 
You can do this easy with linq:

```
var result = yourCollection.Select(x => new YourTempClass(){property1=x.property1});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not want to remove objects, but properties of the objects.

```
public class ClassWithAllProperties
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string device_code { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }
    public string authentication_token { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

var allInstances = new List<ClassWithAllProperties>();

// populate list

var allInstancesButNotAllProperties = allInstances.Select(x => new { id = x.id, authentication_token = x.authentication_token, Status = x.Status }).ToList();
```

Now this list contains only the properties you want. *However* it obviously also does *not* contain instances of `ClassWithAllProperties`. It contains so-called anonymous classes. Classes the compiler builds in the background for you, based on your description in the `new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string device_code { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }
    public string authentication_token { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

...and you have a list of them...

```
List<MyClass> list;
```

You can extract just the properties you want into an anonymous type by using LINQ:

```
var justWhatIWant = list.Select( a => new 
{
    id = a.id,
    authentication_token = a.authentication_token,
    Status = a.Status
});
```

The anonymous type isn't interface-compatible with anything, but you could use it to, say, create some JSON.